# Trying to call an array of Images

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have an Array of images that need to be called depending on the cell that was tapped on. For example, let's say you have five cells and each cell has its own information pertaining to that particular cell. When you tap on cell one, it opens to a new page, and the image shows for that cell that's in the array along with the information that goes along with it. Now when you tap on cell 2 the image populates as well as the information that is specifically for cell two. How can I call an image from an array that pertains to the cell that was tapped? I know how to do it with a string, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with an image. When I try to do it the same way as I did with the string all I get is errors.

here is one part of the code:

```
import UIKit

class FacultyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

var facultyMemeber: [String] = ["Ron Cervantes", "Darice Corey-Gilbert", "Devan Shepard", "Tom Sinclair"]

var image: UIImage  = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "rcervantas"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dcorey"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dshepherd"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tsinclair")]

var bio: [String] = ["Ron is a tech billionaire who finds fulfillment in teaching!", "Darice oversees all aspects of Web design and development for Yale College. Coordinates planning and implementation of new and existing Web projects for Yale College clients. Establishes web design and functionality standards. Works with the Director of IT Planning and Coordination to provide strategic Web solutions for Yale College. The Director strategically plans and implements Web development at Yale College. The Director collaborates with the Dean and upper-level management on matters of Web strategy, and develops and maintains relations with client offices. She supervises the activities of YCWS staff, especially in regard to day-to-day support of client operations. The Director anticipates imminent advances in Web technology, manages contracts with outside design and programming vendors including ITS; and oversees YCWS's budget, administrative and office practices, hiring, and human resource contacts.", "CEO, Chief Technical Officer - XMaLpha Technologies, AOPA Outstanding Flight Instructor of the Year, 2012", "Owner and Senior Consultant at Cynomys Consulting, Adjunct Faculty at Westwood College; formerly Program Chair - Information Technology at Westwood College, Senior Consultant, I.T. Architecture at KPMG CT, Unix Administrator at Bell Labs Lucent"]

var education: [String] = ["MS Management Information Systems | Keller Graduate School of Management 2007 \nBA Business w/concentration in MIS | University of Wisconsin-Parkside 1999", "MBA Information Technology and E-Business | Fairfield University 2002 \nBS Information Systems | Fairfield University 1998", "MS Information Technology | Capella University \nBA Psychology | Wilfrid Laurier University", "MS Computer Science | Loyola University, Chicago, Illinois \nBS Computer Science | Loyola University, Chicago, Illinois"]

var selectedRow: Int = -1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return facultyMemeber.count
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let faculty:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "faculty")!

    faculty.textLabel?.text = facultyMemeber[indexPath.row]

    return faculty
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Faculty", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let detailView: DetailFacultyViewController = segue.destination as! DetailFacultyViewController

    selectedRow = (table.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!

    detailView.facultyNameString = facultyMemeber[selectedRow]
    detailView.bioString = bio[selectedRow]
    detailView.detailImage = image[selectedRow]
    detailView.educationString = education[selectedRow]


}
/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

The other part that it's calling from is:
    import UIKit

```
class DetailFacultyViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var facultyName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var bio: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var education: UILabel!

var facultyNameString: String!
var detailImage: String!
var bioString: String!
var educationString: String!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setFacultyName()
    setBio()
    setEducation()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func setFacultyName () {
    facultyName.text = facultyNameString    }

func setBio() {
    bio.text = bioString
}

func setEducation() {
    education.text = educationString
}

func setImage() {
    image.image = detailImage
}
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Show the code.  Show the errors.

Comment: @CoryT87 please show the code for how you're trying to do it, especially your UITableViewDelegate method that handles the tap on a row.

Comment: I've added the images to the original post

Comment: You need to match data types.  If something is an image, you can't assign a string to it.  If something is defined as UIImage, you can't treat it as an array.

Comment: Do not provide images of code. Provide _code_.

Comment: @CoryT87 Edit your question with the code sample. Not image. It will keep your question intact unlike images that are deleted over time, making your question obsolete.

Comment: @PhillipMills if I can't use images in an array then how will I call them?

Comment: You can use them in an array but you can't treat a single image as if it were an array (which is what the `image[selectedRow]` thing is doing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#imageLiteral(resourceName:)` gives us a `UIImage` so in your case:-
`detailImage` should also be a `UIImage` instead of a `String`

Change:

```
var detailImage: String!
```

to

```
var detailImage: UIImage!
```

And continue what you are doing:

```
image.image = detailImage
```

---

#### Edit:

Also change:

```
var image: UIImage  = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "rcervantas"),...]
```

to

```
//should be an array of images as per your design
var image: [UIImage]  = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "rcervantas"),...]
```

---

And finally call `setImage()`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //...
    setImage()
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I got this error:
`Cannot assign value of type 'String!' to type 'UIImage?'`

Comment: @CoryT87 are you sure? you are doing `image.image = detailImage` but you should be doing  `image.image = UIImage(named: detailImage)`. Try it once more

Comment: I did it on the wrong screen and the error went away but I still have two errors with one of the .swift files. In the first block of code where it says `detailView.detailImage = image[selectedRow]` I'm getting `Type 'UIImage' has no subscript members` and at the top where i have the image array i'm getting `Contextual type 'UIImage' cannot be used with array literal`

Comment: @CoryT87 seems you have a reverse condition. just saw your updated question with code sample. Updating answer.

Comment: I fixed the part that you had changed but that didn't fix the last two errors I'm getting are: In the first block of code where it says `detailView.detailImage = image[selectedRow]` I'm getting `Type 'UIImage' has no subscript members` and at the top where I have the image array I'm getting `Contextual type 'UIImage' cannot be used with array literal`

Comment: @CoryT87 Check updated answer. Just a silly mistake. You have an array of images so it `images` type should be `[UIImage]` not just `UIImage`

Comment: ah ok, I did the change and all my errors are gone but the image doesn't show :/

Comment: @CoryT87 Maybe because you are not calling **`setImage()`!!!** in your `viewWillAppear(_:)`. Anyways, updated answer

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to put the setImage() in the `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @CoryT87 Hah, yeah. Btw, your design is very amateur. Don't use multiple arrays to represent one thing. Use a struct and eventually you will have to deal with only a single array. Try something like `var facultyInfo: [Faculty]` where `Faculty` is a `struct` of 4 objects: `name`, `image`, `bio`, `education`. Then no need for 4 different `arrays`. Have a look online and you'll figure things out. Happy coding :)

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't even think about using a struct. I guess next time I will. Oh, I'm relatively new to coding in Swift, so I'm still learning. Thanks for the tip!